# can't install detectron2 on Windows 10, CUDA 11.2, pytorch = 1.9

Tags: pip, pytorch, conda

Problem:- I am trying to install the detectron2 in Windows 11.
I have cuda 11.2
`pip install torch==1.12.1+cu113 torchvision==0.13.1+cu113 torchaudio==0.12.1 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113`

Issue:-
`python -m pip install -e detectron2-computer-vision`

Logs:-

```
` C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include\crt/host_config.h(160): fatal error C1189: #error:  -- unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version! Only the versions between 2017 and 2019 (inclusive) are supported! The nvcc flag '-allow-unsupported-compiler' can be used to override this version check; however, using an unsupported host compiler may cause compilation failure or incorrect run time execution. Use at your own risk.
        ROIAlignRotated_cuda.cu
        D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
          warnings.warn(
        D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
          warnings.warn(
        D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:370: UserWarning: Attempted to use ninja as the BuildExtension backend but we could not find ninja.. Falling back to using the slow distutils backend.
          warnings.warn(msg.format('we could not find ninja.'))
        D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:305: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
          warnings.warn(f'Error checking compiler version for {compiler}: {error}')
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.2\\bin\\nvcc.exe' failed with exit code 2
        [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [762 lines of output]
    running develop
    running egg_info
    writing detectron2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to detectron2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to detectron2.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to detectron2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    adding license file 'LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'detectron2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'detectron2._C' extension
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWITH_CUDA "-ID:\Computer Vision\detectron2-computer-vision\detectron2\layers\csrc" -ID:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include -ID:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\torch\csrc\api\include -ID:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\TH -ID:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\THC "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include" -ID:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\include -ID:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc "/TpD:\Computer Vision\detectron2-computer-vision\detectron2\layers\csrc\ROIAlignRotated\ROIAlignRotated_cpu.cpp" "/Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\Computer Vision\detectron2-computer-vision\detectron2\layers\csrc\ROIAlignRotated\ROIAlignRotated_cpu.obj" /MD /wd4819 /wd4251 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4275 /wd4018 /wd4190 /EHsc -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_C -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
    ROIAlignRotated_cpu.cpp
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(183): warning C4624: 'c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
            with
            [
                T=at::Tensor
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(367): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>' being compiled
            with
            [
                T=at::Tensor
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(427): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>' being compiled
            with
            [
                T=at::Tensor
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(427): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'c10::OptionalBase<T>' being compiled
            with
            [
                T=at::Tensor
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\ATen/core/TensorBody.h(734): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'c10::optional<at::Tensor>' being compiled
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(395): warning C4624: 'c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
            with
            [
                T=at::Tensor
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(183): warning C4624: 'c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
            with
            [
                T=at::Generator
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(367): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>' being compiled
            with
            [
                T=at::Generator
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(427): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>' being compiled
            with
            [
                T=at::Generator
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(427): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'c10::OptionalBase<T>' being compiled
            with
            [
                T=at::Generator
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\ATen/core/TensorBody.h(800): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'c10::optional<at::Generator>' being compiled
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(395): warning C4624: 'c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
            with
            [
                T=at::Generator
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(183): warning C4624: 'c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
            with
            [
                T=c10::impl::InlineDeviceGuard<c10::impl::VirtualGuardImpl>
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(367): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'c10::constexpr_storage_t<T>' being compiled
            with
            [
                T=c10::impl::InlineDeviceGuard<c10::impl::VirtualGuardImpl>
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(427): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'c10::trivially_copyable_optimization_optional_base<T>' being compiled
            with
            [
                T=c10::impl::InlineDeviceGuard<c10::impl::VirtualGuardImpl>
            ]
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\include\c10/util/Optional.h(427): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'c10::OptionalBase<T>' being compiled
            with
            [
                T=c10::impl::InlineDeviceGuard<c10::impl::VirtualGuardImpl>
            ]`

`.................................................................................................................................................................`
` C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include\crt/host_config.h(160): fatal error C1189: #error:  -- unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version! Only the versions between 2017 and 2019 (inclusive) are supported! The nvcc flag '-allow-unsupported-compiler' can be used to override this version check; however, using an unsupported host compiler may cause compilation failure or incorrect run time execution. Use at your own risk.
    ROIAlignRotated_cuda.cu
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:370: UserWarning: Attempted to use ninja as the BuildExtension backend but we could not find ninja.. Falling back to using the slow distutils backend.
      warnings.warn(msg.format('we could not find ninja.'))
    D:\anaconda3\envs\detectron2\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:305: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      warnings.warn(f'Error checking compiler version for {compiler}: {error}')
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v11.2\\bin\\nvcc.exe' failed with exit code 2
    [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.`
```

System config:
GPU:- GTX 1650
RAM:- 8GB
CUDA 11.2
Python = 3.9

I have tried 2 times creating a new environment but still getting the same error.

I have installed visual studio compiler installed, Is it because of CUDA 11.2? I haven't tried updating my CUDA drivers because on my other environment I am using tensorflow-2.10.

Comment: have you seen `unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version! Only the versions between 2017 and 2019 (inclusive) are supported!`? Which version do you have?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is some error during compilation I was getting the same error, I did a few things that were able to help. And currently I am able to run detectron2 on my windows OS.

1. Uninstall any of the Visual studio version that are not compatible with the CUDA version that you have, i.e. CUDA 11.2. (only visual studio between 2017-2019 both inclusive are supported). Alternatively, you can change the order of PATH environment variable to give precedence to the compatible Visual Studio Version. I know it is not coming up in the error but can help anyways.
2. Install cython and pycocotools (this is what has been suggested in other blog posts where the author was successfully able to install detectron2 on windows), run the commands below:

   pip install cython
   pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI
3. Install Ninja, (this is how I was able to resolve my error) prior to installing ninja the library was not getting installed but simple command below helped,

   pip install ninja
4. Finally, cd to the detectron2 folder (cloned from the git repo) and run the command below,

   pip install -e .

Lastly, if nothing of the above works, update the nvidia graphic driver, (it will also change the CUDA toolkit version installed to the latest version, maybe 12.2), but it still works I guess because of backward compatibility.
(link :[Nvidia grapic driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx))

P.S: I had tried all these steps but I am not 100% sure whether installing ninja or updating the driver finally helped, I installed ninja after updating my driver, and didn't run the command in between. So, not completely sure, at the moment just happy that it installed.

Current config:
Python 3.8.17
pytorch version : 1.8.0 (with CUDA 11.1)
but as I updated my graphic driver to v537.13, my CUDA got updated to 12.2
Nvidia GTX 1080 Ti (Windows 10)